# How to find out the image points of transit image in javafx

Tags: javafx, points

We are  developing a small game of dropping images. We need to find the image X and Y points without an Event like mouseClick() event etc.

Please Help me to find out Points of Moving Image. i.e Points of Transit Image.
We have applied pathtransition on image.

Comment: have you tried any logic, can you share any code or link for what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/PathTransition.html).

> "This Transition creates a path animation that spans its duration. The
>   translation along the path is done by updating the translateX and
>   translateY variables of the node"

Just register a listener with the translateX and translateY properties of the Node you are animating. You can use the boundsInParent property to find its coordinates, including translations, relative to the parent.